# schema.org/Book with multiple authors

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

How would one write markup for a book with multiple authors?

This is what I currently have, it is marked up for just one author:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
    <h1>My Book</h1>
    <p>by
        <span itemprop="author">
            <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                <span itemprop="name">Author 1</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Would I just need to add multiple authors like this?

```
<span itemprop="author">
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <span itemprop="name">Author 1</span>
    </span>
</span>
<span itemprop="author">
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <span itemprop="name">Author 2</span>
    </span>
</span>
<span itemprop="author">
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <span itemprop="name">Author 3</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: That's a lot of spans and very short paragraphs you got there... use `<div>`... and css to style it... not `<p>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, provide multiple `author` properties.

But note that the `itemprop` has to be specified on the element with the `itemscope`.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></span>
  <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></span>
  <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad you got rid of the span containers and p :)